# $event is undefined TypeError in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I am new to Angular JS. So I decided to start doing a small to-do Task Project. But in between, I encountered an error:

> typeerror $event is undefined

I am using `enterAgain` function. We need to double click for editing an existing task. After editing and upon clicking enter button, I am getting the above error.

When I checked in Google, I cam to know that we need to pass the event as function variable. So I passed the variable in `enterAgain` Function. You can see that in the below files. But even though I passed the variable event, still showing error.

Please see the code attached:

```
https://pastebin.com/uBXDjzAH
https://pastebin.com/Qz5yCQ0m
```

Please see the image:

[image]

Please help me to find a solution for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing $event to function  contentEdit(**$event**)  inside **enterAgain** method call.

```
    $scope.enterAgain = function($event,msg) {
        if($event.which == 13 && msg !== "") {
           $scope.contentEdit($event);  // ==> Here you need to pass $event
        }
      }
  });
```

Please check here working code : https://plnkr.co/edit/LiR4bajk0uxMH0mso2yY